# Calculator backspace button

Tags: javascript, calculator

I am trying to figure out what's wrong with my code, because when I try to delete 1 number, it initially gets deleted, but when I click another number it shows again in the display screen as if it wasn't deleted. I have tried everything i know but it's not working!

```js
function backspace() {
  var number1 = document.getElementById("display").value
  var number1 = (document.getElementById("display").value = number1.substr(
    0,
    number1.length - 1
  ))
  refresh()
}

function refresh() {
  document.getElementById("display").value = number1
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use:

```
function backspace() {
  var number1 = document.getElementById("display").value;
  number1 = number1.substring(0, number1.length - 1);
  refresh()
}
```

--- or ---

```
function backspace() {
  var number1 = document.getElementById("display").value;
  number1 = number1.slice(0, -1);
  refresh()
}
```

Source: https://tecadmin.net/remove-last-character-from-string-in-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

`number1` was changed, but it is not in the scope of function `refresh`

The code requires refactoring and clear choice of variable names.

## Scope

Code suffers from scope issues

```
function backspace() {
    var number1 = something //declared here
}
function refresh() {
   //number1 is not accessible here :(
}
```

## Declaring the same variable twice

```
var number1 =.....
var number1 =......
```

please use `let` instead of `var` all the time :)

## Good choice of variables

having `number1` as the name for all variables is a really bad idea.

a better approach would be the following:

```
function backspace(){
    let displayValue = .....
    let changedValue = .....
}
```

Once you change the variable names, you might notice that you are not actually modifying the 'real' number, you are just modifying the value in the DOM (or HTML)

Answer (score 0):

try this shape

```
function backspace() {
  var number1 = document.getElementById("display").value

  number1 = number1.slice(0,-1))
}

function refresh() {
backspace()
}
```